# How to check if the value of a PHP defined constant equals something?

Tags: php, constants

using this:

```
defined('WPLANG')
```

I'm able to check whether the constant is defined or not, but how can I check the value of the constant to use it in an if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
define('WPLANG', 'some value');
if(WPLANG == 'some value'){
  ... 
  ...
}
```

Or

```
define('WPLANG', 1212);
if(WPLANG == 1212){
   ... 
   ...
}
```

It's good to check if the constant is defined before checking its value, since `if ( I_AM_UNDEFINED )` will always be `false`, because the value of an undefined constant is `null`. If you assume it exists and it doesn't, then you could get some unexpected results. So:

```
if( defined('WPLANG') && WPLANG === 'some value' ) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

define('WPLANG','hello');

if(WPLANG == 'hello') {
  echo 'YES';
}

?>
```

Comment: I think you mean `define('WPLANG','hello');` not, `defined`. `defined` is used to check if the constant has been defined, not to define one.

Answer (score 0):

The `defined()` function checks whether or not a given constant exists.

```
if(defined('WPLANG'))
    echo 'exists';
```

You can compare constants in the same way as variable, i.e. <, >, ==, etc.  So if you wanted to check the value of a constant, simply do this:

```
if(WPLANG == 'en-US')
    echo 'set to en-US';
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is my preferred way.

```
// Testing if WPLANG exists
if ( !defined('WPLANG') ){
    define('WPLANG', 'wplang_value');
} 

// Testing if WPLANG equals a certain value
if ( WPLANG == 'wplang_value' ){
    echo WPLANG; 
}
```